# Disabling gatekeeper functionality on a single file

Tags: gatekeeper

I downloaded the latest version of [Pact CLI Tools](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases), and I cannot run it (by launching the pact executable) since it launches me an error (In french):

> Impossible d'ouvrir "xxx" car le développeur ne peut pas être vérifié

Roughly translated to english:

> Impossible to open "xxx" because the developer couldn't be verified

xxx was at first the ruby executable bundled with the tool.

I managed to remove the error on the executables by Command-clicking them + open, but I have now this error with two files, when I run the pact executable :

- stringio.bundle
- encdb.bundle

I tried to change the files rights (`chmod 777`) and removing their extended attributes (`xattr -c`), but it changed nothing.

I associated the .bundle files to VSCode to be able to command+click them. They are opening in vscode without any alert message, but I still have the previous error when trying to launch pact from the command line.

I saw this verification was made with GateKeeper and there is a way to fully deactivate the functionality, but it sounds risky.

How can I disable the verification for these files only ?

Comment: So you are saying that you get the "developer verificaiton" message when you try to open these bundles from VSCode?

Comment: @nohillside no, sorry, I didn't explain well (I'll update the question) :
I CAN open these with vscode without error
But when I launch the pact executable on my terminal, I still have the same error messages

Comment: Can you please copy/paste the Terminal comannd you run, any relevant text output you get in Terminal and actual the error messages you get?

Comment: Hmmm, apparently locate didn't found the correct file. I'll try something and go back to you

Comment: Yup, it worked !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, apparently I was trying to correct the wrong files, the `locate` functionality didn't show me the ones I needed to fix.

So, `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine filename` was the correct answer to "How can I disable Gatekeeper on a specific file".

In order to disable the alert on all the files at once, I just made a recursive call :

`xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine dir/`

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the com.apple.quarantine attribute only, rather than indiscriminately clearing all attributes from all files.

Comment: @benwiggy you're right, I've updated my answer.